# hg clone git:.... aborts: failing connection?

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

When trying to clone a git repository using Mercurial over hg-git:

```
hg clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
destination directory: rails
importing Hg objects into Git
abort: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

It fails, but why? I can successfully clone hg repositories over http.

Comment: Can you successfully clone git repos using git?  Is it possible a port is blocked?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to clone with Mercurial 2.0.1 and the latest version of hg-git (`32afa497834d`) and it worked fine:

```
$ hg clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
target folder: rails
importing git objects into hg                                                   
updating to branch default                                   
2363 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved         
$ cd rails
$ hg bookmarks
   1-2-stable                6587:93df9ec91d74
   2-0-stable                10433:a74a77f2c7df
   2-1-stable                22955:4c14fc65e13c
   2-2-stable                22928:b32f7da4c135
   2-3-stable                28837:e769c35f4340
   3-0-stable                31725:a189c6d4c685
   3-1-stable                31878:48eca81a94da
   3-2-stable                32018:6fdea401d4ed
   compressor                26886:23cc0919b32e
   deps_refactor             19317:9e47f0c5d1cf
   encoding                  17779:b3f42950528b
 * master                    32028:2516d736e018
   sass-cleanup              25967:5f871a0fbe08
   serializers               30995:00982814bb34
```

So I guess you were just unlucky with your network, or maybe GitHub had a temporary problem.